# Tree endomorphism and distance of uncovered vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}$
Let $T$ be a tree.
$f$ is an endomorphism of $T$, if $uv$ is an edge in $T$, then either $f(u)f(v)$ is an edge in $T$ or $f(u)=f(v)$.

$d_T(x,y)$ is the length (# of edges) of the unique $xy$-path in $T$. Let $d_T(X,Y) = \max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y} d_T(x,y)$ and 
$\diam_T(X) = \max_{x,y\in X} d_T(x,y)$.

**Conjecture:**
Let $T=(V,E)$ be a tree, $f:V\to V$ is an endomorphism of $T$. $U=f(V)$. Let $P$ be a path of $k$ nodes and is a subgraph of $T$. If $f(P)$ consists of $j$ nodes, then either $\diam_T(\bar{U})\geq k-1$, or $d_T(\bar{U},U)\geq k-j$.

This conjecture is true when the tree is a path. I wonder does it work in general.

Comment: This question does not make much sense to me. A tree is a graph with no loops, and a reflexive graph always has a loop (assuming it is nonempty), so I conclude that reflexive trees do not exist.

Comment: I have modified the question. I updated the definition of endomorphism and removed reflexive graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a constructive proof, I've found a counterexample. Consider the following tree $T$
[image: Tree]
For this tree, a maximum length path is from $1$ to $8$ and has a length of $7$ edges. Then let
$$f(9)=1$$
$$f(10)=2$$
$$f(n)=3$$
for all other values of $n$. Then $U=f(T)$ is exactly the linear graph
$$U=(1,2,3)$$
It is clear that
$$k=|P|=7$$
$$j=|f(P)|=0$$
$$\textrm{diam}_T(\overline{U})=4<k-1=6$$
$$d_T(\overline{U},U)=5<k-j=7$$
The reason the proof fails is because $f(P)$ is not necessarily of the same length of the longest path between a point in $U$ to a point in $U$ which is adjacent to $\overline{U}$.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I should have stated that $P$ is a subgraph of $T$. I've updated the question.

Comment: I don't think that fixes it. I've edited my post to provide a counterexample.

Comment: $d_T$ is not a symmetric function. $d_T(U,\bar{U})=1$ but $d_T(\bar{U},U)=3$, and I'm concerned with $d_T(\bar{U},U)$.

Comment: In this graph, $d_T(x,y)\leq 2$ is it not?

Comment: $d_T(1,4)=3$. The unique path from 1 to 4 is {1,2},{1,3},{1,4}. It has 3 edges.

Comment: I must be confused by your definition of $d_T(x,y)$: your statement says it is the length of the minimum edged path between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I see I can simplify the definition by never mention graphs, so it is just the length of x-y path. Still where does 2 come from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96877/discussion-between-nicholas-parris-and-chao-xu).